# The Axioms of Shinobi Combat

Tags: naruto

I was reading a [Naruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_(series)) [FanFiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_fiction), [Not ANBU](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11838408/1/). It mentions the 'Axioms of Shinobi Combat', which are basically guidelines governing any violent exchange between two people or parties.

> "Because we haven't fully matured ninjutsu has less utility for us as it's more costly as a proportion of total chakra than it would be for an adult. **This comes from the concept of chakra advantage, which states that if you have spent less proportional chakra than your opponent in an otherwise equal exchange, you now hold the advantage**. For this reason taijutsu and bukijutsu are the mainstay in early training."

This is, basically one of the axioms. In non-Naruto terms, *If you spend a lesser fraction of your energy than your opponent, you're in a better position*.

There are a few other, casually implied axioms too, like *A weapon to any lethal point on your body will kill you*. Armor does not apply, since if you hit armor, you aren't *actually* hitting a lethal point. Just the covering.

There are some, like *You can't hit what you can't see/hear/smell/sense*, or *It doesn't matter if you can see it if you aren't fast enough to react*, which are pretty much obvious.

Are these three enough to completely cover all potential situations? If not, what else must be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

I don't think the given aspects truly cover genjutsu. Under genjutsu,

- The target may use no chakra at all but still at a huge disadvantage
- There is no use of weaponry so I guess it is unrelated to the second axiom.
- Under genjutsu you actually see something but your perception of reality is compromised.

Even if you assume that genjutsu falls on the third axiom, the closest one in my opinion, there are some extreme techniques that cannot be covered. A good example would be **izanagi**. Although it costs an eye, we do not know how much chakra it requires so chakra-wise the user of izanagi may be at an advantage in that particular combat. This advantage comes at a great cost, but it is not covered in these axioms.

A very good example for izanagi is the [Tobi-Konan battle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mq2xeWXKiWc). Konan gives everything to destroy Tobi, but using izanagi, Tobi easily gains upperhand.

Comment: Well, that's a fine point! So maybe one could be *The more distorted your perception of reality is, the bigger disadvantage you are in*.

Comment: And as for the Tobi-Konan battle, another phrase from the same story comes to mind: "What was common for all S-Ranked Shinobi was that they broke at least one of these Axioms."

Comment: I think there is actually no way to cover all aspects of shinobi combat with a finite number of rules. Still, it would be hard to explain Totsuka Blade, cursed marks, tailed beasts etc. Not only shinobi combat is extremely complex, but also Naruto has a good number of plot holes providing countless exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't get a Tailed Beast Bomb in a fight between three Kumo Chuunin and an Iwa Jonin. As is said, rules, not exceptions must dictate behaviour.

Comment: Well, for training cadets, three rules + something that covers genjutsu better might be enough :)